# Need help parsing json output with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the below json file and I'm trying to parse a particular field from it using jq

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.analytics.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.analytics.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "analytics"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.applmgmt.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.applmgmt.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "applmgmt"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.certificatemanagement.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [
              "GREEN"
            ],
            "default_message": "Health is GREEN",
            "id": "certificatemanagement.health.statuscode"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.certificatemanagement.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "certificatemanagement"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.cis-license.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "The License Service is operational.",
            "id": "cis.license.health.ok"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.cis-license.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "cis-license"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.cm.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.cm.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "cm"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.content-library.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "Database server connection is GREEN.",
            "id": "com.vmware.vdcs.vsphere-cs-lib.db_health_green"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.content-library.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "content-library"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.eam.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "",
            "id": "cis.eam.statusOK"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.eam.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "eam"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.imagebuilder.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.imagebuilder.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "imagebuilder"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.mbcs.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.mbcs.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "mbcs"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.netdumper.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.netdumper.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "netdumper"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.perfcharts.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "health.statsReoptInitalizer.green",
            "id": "health.statsReoptInitalizer.green"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.perfcharts.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "perfcharts"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.pschealth.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.pschealth.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "pschealth"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.rbd.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.rbd.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "rbd"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.rhttpproxy.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.rhttpproxy.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "rhttpproxy"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.sca.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.sca.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "sca"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.sps.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.sps.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "sps"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.statsmonitor.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "Appliance monitoring service is healthy.",
            "id": "com.vmware.applmgmt.mon.health.healthy"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.statsmonitor.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "statsmonitor"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.topologysvc.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [
              "GREEN"
            ],
            "default_message": "Health is GREEN",
            "id": "topologysvc.health.statuscode"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.topologysvc.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "topologysvc"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.updatemgr.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.updatemgr.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "updatemgr"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vapi-endpoint.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [
              "2021-09-24T14:56:06UTC",
              "2021-09-24T14:56:07UTC"
            ],
            "default_message": "Current vApi Endpoint health status is created between 2021-09-24T14:56:06UTC and 2021-09-24T14:56:07UTC.",
            "id": "com.vmware.vapi.endpoint.healthStatusProducedTimes"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vapi-endpoint.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vapi-endpoint"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vcha.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "DISABLED",
        "description_key": "cis.vcha.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "vcha"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vmcam.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.vmcam.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "vmcam"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vmonapi.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vmonapi.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vmonapi"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vmware-postgres-archiver.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "VMware Archiver service is healthy.",
            "id": "cis.vmware-postgres-archiver.health.healthy"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vmware-postgres-archiver.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vmware-postgres-archiver"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vmware-vpostgres.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "VMware Postgres service is healthy.",
            "id": "cis.vmware-vpostgres.health.healthy"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vmware-vpostgres.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vmware-vpostgres"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vpxd.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [
              "vCenter Server",
              "GREEN"
            ],
            "default_message": "{0} health is {1}",
            "id": "vc.health.statuscode"
          },
          {
            "args": [
              "VirtualCenter Database",
              "GREEN"
            ],
            "default_message": "{0} health is {1}",
            "id": "vc.health.statuscode"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vpxd.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vpxd"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vpxd-svcs.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [
          {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "Tagging service is in a healthy state",
            "id": "cis.tagging.health.status"
          }
        ],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vpxd-svcs.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vpxd-svcs"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vsan-dps.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "MANUAL",
        "description_key": "cis.vsan-dps.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STOPPED"
      },
      "key": "vsan-dps"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vsan-health.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vsan-health.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vsan-health"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vsm.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vsm.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vsm"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vsphere-client.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vsphere-client.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vsphere-client"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "name_key": "cis.vsphere-ui.ServiceName",
        "startup_type": "AUTOMATIC",
        "health_messages": [],
        "health": "HEALTHY",
        "description_key": "cis.vsphere-ui.ServiceDescription",
        "state": "STARTED"
      },
      "key": "vsphere-ui"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried different combinations that I felt should work and can't get it

`jq '.[].value.health' vm_services.json`
jq: error (at vm_services.json:432): Cannot index array with string "value"

`jq '.[] | .value.health' vm_services.json`
jq: error (at vm_services.json:432): Cannot index array with string "value"

Comment: `.[].value.health` works perfectly with the input you gave us here, so the problem is in whatever you *didn't* include.

Comment: I added the full json output

Comment: Nope, still no error, and the file you provided is 430 lines long, so it doesn't have a line 432.

Comment: For some reason the beginning got cut off, I have updated it again.

Comment: Okay, that makes it a completely different structure. See 0stone0's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON starts with:

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
```

This indicates that you're dealing with an object.

Your command, `'.[].value.health'` tries to loop over an array.

To do so, you'll need to select the first `value` key, then use that as an array.

```
jq '.value[].value.health' tst.input
```

Will produce:

```
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
null
null
null
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
null
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
null
null
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
null
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
"HEALTHY"
```

Comment: Re "*Your command, '.[].value.health' tries to loop over an array.*",  That's not true. [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/VytR8YJsBP)

Comment: Yep, your completely right, could you help me rephrase the sentence @ikegami?

Comment: "You want the elements of the array in `.value`, so you want `.value[]` rather than `.[].value`"